# How do I detect if axios request is in loading phase while using async/await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios

I need to detect if the axios request (with async/await) is in loading phase. Because, I need to disable a button if the request is loading.

So, this is the line of code:

```
const response = await API.get("/url", options);
```

Now, I need to disable a certain button if this request is in loading phase. But, I'm stuck on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
setState(true) //to initiate loading
const response = await API.get("/url", options);
setState(false) //to turn off loading
```

```js
try{
setState(true) //to initiate loading
const response = await API.get("/url", options);
}
catch(err){}
finally{
setState(false) //to turn off loading
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this behavior by using the following steps:

**1 -** Create a state called `isLoading` and initialize it to `false`.

```js
const [isloading, setIsloading] = useState(false);
```

**2 -** Get the current state of data fetching:

```js
const fetchingData = async () => {
    try {
        setIsloading(true); // Set loading before sending API request
        const response = await API.get("/url", options);
        ....
        setIsloading(false); // Stop loading
    } catch (error) {
        setIsloading(false); // Stop loading in case of error
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

**3 -** Disable button conditionally:

```html
<button disabled={isloading ? true : false}> button disabled while fetching data</button>
```

This is a sample demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-jmt8mq?file=/demo.js).